# Changing laravel eloquent date mutators

Tags: php, laravel, mutators

Today I was cleaning up my code and wanted to make it as reusable as possible. I ran into the issue regarding my createdAt mutator.

What I have: On our front-end side, we do have 2 different inputs. We do have 1 for the date, and 1 for the time:

```html
<input type="text" name="date" class="form-control datepicker" required>
<input type="text" name="time" class="form-control timepicker" required>
```

These 2 I mix together once I do receive the request to a created_at attribute in my news controller:

```php
public function store(ManageNewsRequest $request, Project $project)
{
    // Add user id, receive dates and add the image
    $request['user_id'] = Auth::user()->id;
    $request['created_at'] = [$request->input('date'),$request->input('time')];
    $request['image'] = $request->file('image');

    $project->news()->save(new News($request->all()));

    Session::flash('alert', 'News post added');
    return redirect()->route('admin.projectadmin.news.index', $project->id);
}
```

In my model I did create a mutator, which should be converting the date:

```php
public function setCreatedAtAttribute($dateAndTime)
{
    $this->attributes['created_at'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d.m.Y H:i', $dateAndTime[0].' '.$dateAndTime[1]);
}
```

However, in any case I always do receive a carbon object as $dateAndTime, and this object is the current time. It is not the time and date I receive. I have checked if the date and time are set, and they are set properly. So I somehow loose my array, even though I've set the mutator.

Why does my mutator does not get taken into account?

Comment: What is the question??

Comment: Oh sorry added it, lol. It does not take my mutator. As I already said above, I always do get a Carbon object at $dateAndTime, but I do want my array which I set before

Comment: That is a setter and not a getter...If you want to present your date in some other format you need a getter...but I am still not sure what are you trying to do?

Comment: created_at ist ein default Feld von timestamps() du sollst es nicht machen. Hast du Problem mit dem speichern oder den richtigen Format zu zeigen?

Comment: I know that this is a setter. I also know that it is a default value generated by timestamps(), but I want to be able to modify it in case someone posts a different date on our backend. The issue is as I described above: When I set the  $request['created_at'] = [$request->input('date'),$request->input('time')]; the mutator does not get the array, it shows me a carbon object which should be an array instead.

Comment: This part I don't understand: "I want to be able to modify it in case someone posts a different date on our backend."

Comment: created_at is usually set by laravel. However, users are able to edit the date  in the backend in case they would like to publish the news later. This is what I set from front-end to backend. I do set the array at the top, but I get a Carbon object right at $dateAndTime, which is supposed to be none

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155989/discussion-between-lewis4u-and-astinox).